# How to create a NSPanel modally popuped from NSWindow (Cocoa programming)

Tags: xcode, modal-dialog, nswindow, nspanel

like NSPanel displayed after a button clicked in the NSWindow.

I looked for a lot but there is no simple example.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
-(IBAction)showButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] beginSheet:panelOutlet
                                   modalForWindow:self.window
                                    modalDelegate:self
                                   didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                                      contextInfo:nil];
}
```

Attention:

> Don't forget to uncheck `NSPanel`'s **Visible At Launch** checkbox in
>   *Attributes Inspector* and **Release When Closed** if you will use this panel not once.

Result:

[image: Screenshot image]

Comment: Swift equivalent ? ty

Comment: Isn't this `NSSheet` instead of `NSPanel`?