# Which Cocoa Animated NSView Subclass is it?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I try to figure out, which NSViewSubclass is the overlapping one :

[[[NSView Animated Overlap](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9425025/NSView_Animated_Overlap.gif)]]

Have you got any idea ?

I hope it's a Cocoa NSView Subclass... and if it's not, I would create a NSAnimated subview.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at NSPanel which does what you seem to be looking for

Answer (score 0):

Ho, nice !

Actually, I never thought NSPanel would be used like that...

[how-to-create-a-nspanel-modally-popuped-from-nswindow-cocoa-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881164/how-to-create-a-nspanel-modally-popuped-from-nswindow-cocoa-programming)

Many thanks !